# How do I deactivate GMail meter emails?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I de-activate the google apps skript: activityReport. I tried out the gmail meter and finally deleted the document in google docs. now, every night I receive a report, see below:

Ihr Skript, Gmail Meter, konnte nicht erfolgreich fertiggestellt werden. Unten finden Sie eine Zusammenfassung der Fehler. Klicken Sie hier, um die Trigger für dieses Skript zu konfigurieren oder Ihre Einstellung für den Empfang künftiger Benachrichtigungen zu ändern.

"
Details:

Beginn  Funktion    Fehlermeldung   Auslöser    Ende
14.06.12 01:15  activityReport  Leider ist ein Serverfehler aufgetreten. Warten Sie eine Weile und versuchen Sie es später erneut.  time-based  14.06.12 01:15
Mit freundlichen Grüßen

Google Apps Script
"

How do I de-activate this?

Regards
  Roland

Answer (score 21):

Open any Google Spreadsheet , then open the script editor, go to 'resources' > triggers > all your triggers > and there delete the one called 'activityreport', it runs daily between 1AM and 2 AM. And that's it.

EDIT : Here is a [link to Romain Vialard instructions](http://blog.gmailmeter.com/2016/uninstalling-the-legacy-gmail-meter-script/) that explains it clearly.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to open the Mail Data spreadsheet in order to get to the triggers.  Might be due to a recent change in the way the script editor works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the uninstall link I received when I first signed up for Gmail Meter. I recently used it to uninstall, removing the app's permission and trigger:

https://script.google.com/macros/d/MVg3JbkghVMfVvxN1M5l0HJrpgLqM6szJ/manage/uninstall

I'm guessing the macro URL is the same for everyone, but if it doesn't work for you let me know and I'll remove this answer so as to not cause confusion.

Comment: I've used the link too. And it worked! It's been a week since then and I can confirm that the emails stopped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the inconveniences of the legacy Gmail Meter. We have actually deprecated that version of the tool due to lack of support for the Apps Script platform. There are three major steps to uninstalling this version, the third of which has been described above:

## Revoking the script's access to your account

The first being revoking permissions for Gmail Meter by visiting your Google account page here, selecting Connected apps & sites underneath the Sign-in & security section on the left. On next page, clicking Manage apps in order to view the authorized applications.

From this list you will be able to find the authorization for Gmail Meter to access your account. To revoke access, simply click on the Remove button.

## Deleting the Gmail Meter Drive file

Once authorization for the legacy Gmail Meter has been revoked, the next step is to delete the file called “Gmail Meter Data – Do not delete” stored within the root folder of your Google Drive. This file is where the raw data for your account is stored prior to analysis. Also make sure to empty the Trash within your Drive to ensure complete uninstall.

## Deactivating the script triggers on your account

Finally, you will then need to delete the script triggers still active within your Google account. Script triggers are essential to Apps Script and determine when scripts are run. The original signup email is helpful as it contains a button to delete these script triggers.

The alternative is to follow the instructions below and manually delete all script triggers that are associated with activityReport. In order to do so, please do the following:

1. Open your browser in incognito mode (CTRL+SHIFT+N for Chrome).
2. Go to https://script.google.com and login to your Google account.
3. Click on 'Edit' and then select 'All your triggers' from the dropdown menu.
4. If you are prompted to 'Edit Project Name,' any name will do and
   feel free to simply click OK.
5. Give the system a moment to save the new project.
6. Then you should see a list of all Apps Script triggers active within your Google
   account. Remove all triggers labeled 'activityReport.'

Thanks again for your support and understanding.